# Express routing to a React app based on login status

Tags: node.js, express

I have a small Express app that handles login/logout and renders a React app that takes over the routing from that point. However, I have a requirement to not render the React app if the user isn't logged in.
I have four routes defined in the Express part: `/`, `/login`, `/logout` and `/user` (used for fetching user data from the React app).

`/` does this:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    res.redirect('/react-entry-point');
  }
  res.redirect('/login');
});
```

and this seems to work. However, if go to `/react-entry-point` directly from my browser, I do end up in the React app. I don't usually work with backend so I'm not sure how best to tackle this. Can I somehow catch the `/react-entry-point` request (or any request for that matter) and check it for `req.user` and redirect if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a middleware function that checks if `req.user` is present and assign it to appropriate routes:

```js
app.get("/", checkAuth, (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("/react-entry-point");
});

app.get("/user", checkAuth, (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({...});
});

function checkAuth(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.user) {
    res.redirect("/login");
    return;
  }
  next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create `Guard/Protected Route` inside your react app where you will be able to  validate you session just before you serving proper router content. Don't forget to validate session data on backend.

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    session.isLoggedIn ?
    <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/login',
          state: { from: props.location }
        }} />
  )} />
);
```

and then:

```
<ProtectedRoute path='/protected' component={Protected} />
```

You can read example code here: https://github.com/lblima/react-protected-routes

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't help since I need to avoid even rendering the react app if a user isn't logged in.

Comment: Then make whole app after that protected route, and leave only login router available to not logged in users.

Comment: doesn't help; the bundle would still be loaded on the client

Comment: Yes, react app is bundled... I don't really understand right now what do you want to do. You want to use application without downloading it?